# Using Ag-grid with object of nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid

I am trying to use ag-grid with an api that gives the following code

```
{
  "rates": {
    "btc": {
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "unit": "BTC",
      "value": 1,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
(snip) 
}
```

And my ag-grid is set up in the following way

```
 <AgGridReact
            rowSelection="multiple"
                rowData={rowData}>
                <AgGridColumn field="btc"  filter={true} checkboxSelection={true} sortable={true}></AgGridColumn>
                <AgGridColumn field="eth" filter={true} checkboxSelection={true} sortable={true}></AgGridColumn>
                <AgGridColumn field="ltc" filter={true} checkboxSelection={true} sortable={true}></AgGridColumn>
            </AgGridReact>
```

So far that is giving me an error. I am not understanding why, because the code is working fine when I use a different api. The other api returns the following

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
```

And my working grid is set up in the following way

```
<AgGridReact
            rowSelection="multiple"
                rowData={rowData}>
                <AgGridColumn field="name"  filter={true} checkboxSelection={true} sortable={true}></AgGridColumn>
                <AgGridColumn field="phone" filter={true} checkboxSelection={true} sortable={true}></AgGridColumn>
                <AgGridColumn field="email" filter={true} checkboxSelection={true} sortable={true}></AgGridColumn>
            </AgGridReact>
```

I've noticed that the difference is the working api is an array of objects, while the one that is not working is an object with nested objects.

The full code is [here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/cryptocurrency-price-grid/blob/main/src/App.js) for anyone to view

thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put a demo of your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-glade-409ok?file=/src/App.js) with a few changes:

- "btc", "eth", and "ltc" are objects themselves rather than simple fields, so having them as columns wouldn't make much sense. Maybe you meant to iterate on these objects and view their "name", "unit", "value", and "type" instead. I've replaced the columns with the latter 4.
- These objects are inside of an object with a single field: "rates". Therefore, in your last `.then()` you'd have to

  ```js
  let rates = rowData.rates
  ```

  But `rates` is still an object, not an array. So you'll also have to

  ```js
  let newRowData = Object.values(rates)
  ```

  This `newRowData` variable is an array of objects consisting of the values of "btc", "eth", "ltc", etc., like so:

  ```json
  [{
    "name": "Bitcoin",
    "unit": "BTC",
    "value": 1.0,
    "type": "crypto"
  }, {
    "name": "Ether",
    "unit": "ETH",
    "value": 33.13,
    "type": "crypto"
  },
  ...
  }]
  ```
- Finally, I've put the `console.log()` inside the last `.then()`, since `fetch()` is asynchronous, and there is no guarantee that `console.log(rowData)` would print the newly fetched data on the console.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I will study what you have done here. Thank you!